# What does it mean when my question is "edited" and how can I investigate?

Tags: support, editing, edits

My [last question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030796/printers-conf-permanent-changes) was "edited", can somebody explain:

1. What this means exactly.
2. How do I see what "edits" were made.
3. How do I contact the "editor" should I disagree with the "editing"

Comment: I added a code block to make your question easier to read. I didn't add or delete anything.

Comment: Here https://askubuntu.com/tour and here https://askubuntu.com/help specificaly here https://askubuntu.com/help/editing

Comment: @pomsky will be notified with this comment because they edited this question! That should help answer C!

Comment: Yep, don't forget to put an `@` before the user-nickname.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Chilli555, also to all the other readers who responded. I'm not quite sure how you add a "code block" but I'll try and find out for future posts. @Hal_v

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Sorry Muru and Zanna, but in this case it's better to leave A, B, C in as the A and B have the same answer and C a different one, unless you can teach me how to edit both the Q and my answer to reflect what OP is asking...

Comment: @Fabby uh, just use 1, 2 and 3 instead?

Comment: @muru sometimes I cannot see the trees because of the wood...  Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 and 2 can be answered by [this link](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1030796/revisions) which is available as well below your original question.

3 can be answered by looking below your question:

[image]

One of the overall nice guys on this site (Chili555, our resident WiFi surgeon) edited your question for better readability...

For more detailed information go here: https://askubuntu.com/help/editing as per Mark Kirby's comment.

## ;-)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, I feel I have a better understanding  of the "mechanics" of the site as a result of these. Having the chance to have questions answered is so important and one of the reasons I've started using Ubuntu. Hal_v.

Comment: No worries.  And you never have to sign your comments.  The system does that for you...  **;-)**

Answer (score 8):

Simply, editing means changing.

Anyone with less than 2000 reputation can suggest a change to your post. You can approve or reject that. Anyone with more than 2000 reputation can unilaterally change a post without any approval process. People with more than 2000 reputation also will approve the edits made by people with less than 2000. It takes two people approving it to be approved.

You can see the edits by clicking the link "edited X" (e.g. "edited yesterday") above the photo of the most recent editor. This gives you an edit history:

[image]

Here we can see

If you disagree with the edits because they changed the meaning of your post you can edit them back. It's your post. However, don't keep doing this - if they make their edit again, come here ([meta.askubuntu.com](https://meta.askubuntu.com)) and ask a question about it!

If you just want to discuss an answer, you can add a comment below your post which starts with `@username` - for example, if I comment below this question `@pomsky`, pomsky will get a notification. This works for anyone in the edit history!

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Thank you also, is there a way I can close this post as I feel people have spent enough time on giving such detailed answers? I couldn't seem to find anything on the help pages, but at 81 I do tend to miss things more frequently than before.

Comment: @hal_v there is no need to close this, people will find it less. Accepting an answer is enough!